# Can't get Travis API token using Github token

Tags: travis-ci

According to [Travis API documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/api#with-a-github-token), for getting Travis API token I need send POST HTTP request on special address:

```
POST /auth/github HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: MyClient/1.0.0
Accept: application/vnd.travis-ci.2+json
Host: api.travis-ci.org
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 37

{"github_token":"YOUR GITHUB TOKEN"}
```

But when I do this I receive 403 error with `Unexpected 'y'` message.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Or there is something specific with Travis API?

Comment: After one day of Travis support disturbing, I resolved this problem making HTTP  request using `curl` command and without 'Content-Length' header which mentioned in Travis docs. Here is the example of the command: `curl -v -L -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "User-Agent: TravisMyClient/1.0.0" -H "Accept: application/vnd.travis-ci.2+json" -X POST -d '{"github_token":"<github-token>"}`

Answer (score 0):

I made it work like this:

```
http post https://api.travis-ci.org/auth/github Content-Type:application/json User-Agent:TravisMyClient/1.0.0 Accept:application/vnd.travis-ci.2+json github_token=<enter_your_github_token>
```

im using HTTPie instead of curl.